# Are Docker Cloud nodes managed?

Tags: azure, docker

If I create a node on Azure through the Docker Cloud Service, will the Azure vm be managed for me? For example, will I have to manage security on the VM (firewalls etc), and updates?

Answer (score 0):

Every virtual machine created in Azure will be secured by Microsoft by various ways. But here it would be helpful to know what you mean by the security - some of features are enabled as a service.

There is [Azure Trust Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/) where you can find what Microsoft does for the security.

Basic information, including some Security-Features-As-a-Service, can be found on the [Azure VMs landing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/security/).

Comment: What I'd like to know is, should we treat these nodes as IAAS or PAAS? For instance, an Azure cloud service needs no tending to (Microsoft patches them every couple of weeks), whereas upgrades need to be managed for a VM in Azure. Security wise, the sort of thing I'm thinking about is creating endpoints on the node (Azure VM). Would Docker Cloud be capable of that?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I am not sure if i follow you - do you mean VMs in Docker Cloud, or integration between Docker Cloud and Azure, or...? Basically, in terms of containers, the update of the VM consists of 1) OS, 2) orchestrator, 3) application. OS and orchestrator can be updated using scripts. Or, if that answer does not relate to your question, could you please elaborate?

Comment: What we're really looking for is a service where all we have to worry about is managing containers via the Docker rest api, something like Orchard used to do (https://www.orchardup.com). Is this what setting up a Node through Docker Cloud would provide?

Comment: Ah, makes sense now! Yes, Docker Cloud has the API you can use for management.